# Visual Basic Excel Font Color

Tags: excel, vba

I want to determine the color of a current cell.
When I

```
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Font.Color
```

I get back a number. In this case 24832
How do I determine the proper RGB value of this color given that I only have this number?
Is there some function that turns an int into RGB(0,0,0)?

Comment: What color is the Font in this example?

Comment: do you know what binary is, and hex actually is? Convert 24832 to HEX (base 16), is that the color of this font?

Comment: 24832 (base 10) = 0000 0000 0110 0001 0000 0000 (base 2) = 006100 (base 16).. is the font color a dark blue?

Comment: if I remember correctly.. VBA doesn't do RGB it does like RBG in it's value assignments or something like that..

Comment: or, I could be confusing RGB with RGBA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in VBA conversion to RGB, you will need to write your own.

Try This

```
Function ColorToRgb(Color As Variant) As Variant
    ' return #Value Error for invalid colors
    If Color < 0 Or Color > 16777215 Then
        ColorToRgb = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If

    ReDim Res(1 To 3) As Variant
    ' Treating Color as a 24 bit number
    Res(1) = Color Mod 256          ' Red value: left most 8 bits
    Res(2) = Color \ 256 Mod 256    ' Green value: middle 8 bits
    Res(3) = Color \ 65536 Mod 256  ' Blue value: right most 8 bits

    ColorToRgb = Res
End Function
```

Comment: Great. What is the background on that integer value as a color value?
The ColorIndex doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: hmm.. can you elaborate on what you're doing here, for completeness.

Comment: Added explanation as inline comments

Comment: @Ken `ColorIndex` is quite different to `Color`.  From Excel VBA help on ColoroIndex: _The color is specified as an index value into the current color palette..._

Comment: I'm not sure about the `ReDim` in `ReDim Res`.. does that require it be dim first in VBA?

Comment: @brettCaswell. `ReDim` Can be used instead of `Dim` to declare a dynamic array. (You could `Dim Res as Variant` first if you want, but it is not required.  Note: I always use Option Explict in my code)

Answer (score 2):

This is a much quicker bit mask for RGB components:

```
Function RGBComp(Clr As Variant) As Variant
    If Clr >= 0 Or Clr <= 16777215 Then
        RGBComp = Array(Clr And &HFF, (Clr And &HFF00&) \ &H100&, (Clr And &HFF0000) \ &H10000)
    Else
        RGBComp = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End Function
```